# Calculate centroids using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-2, centroids

I am trying to calculate the centroids of polygons using PyQGIS.

When I calculate the centroids with the interface (Vector --> Geometry Tools --> Polygon Centroids) everything works out.

However, I fail to reproduce the same using the python console in QGIS (version 2.18.16).

Following the history output after conducting the operation manually as well as the [QGIS documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_geometry_tools/polygoncentroids.html), I use this line of code:

```
processing.runalg("qgis:polygoncentroids", shapefile, "memory:")
```

This produces the error:

```
NameError: name 'processing' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I still feel new to this site. Please let me know if and how I can improve my question to help you answer it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To solve your problem you should only import the module before executing the command (usually this is not necessary).

```
import processing
```

If you want to use QGIS 3 to calculate the centroids of a polygon layer you can execute the following command:

```
processing.run("native:centroids", {'INPUT':'D:/polygons.shp','ALL_PARTS':False,'OUTPUT':'memory:'})
```

If you have a MultiPolygon layer and for each part you want to calculate its centroid you can execute the following command:

```
processing.run("native:centroids", {'INPUT':'D:/polygons.shp','ALL_PARTS':True,'OUTPUT':'memory:'})
```

Answer (score 3):

You must Import the processing library

```
import processing
shapefile = "c:/tar/polygon.shp"
processing.runandload("qgis:polygoncentroids", shapefile, "memory")
```